# Moving footer (page number) on odd pages a bit to the right

Tags: margins, footer, customize, mylatexformat

Using this Latex template

- https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/annual-reviews-style-3-template/nwnzyzhmrkpw

I would like to move the page number/the footer of odd pages around 2cm to the right.

How can this be done?

Background: I managed to change the margins of the main text (smaller margins), but the foot note (page number) of odd pages did not move with the increased text width of the main text. Therefore I would like to move the footer now manually on odd pages.

Here is a MWE:

```
% This is a template file for Annual Reviews 1 column Journals
%
% Compilation using ar-1col-S2O.cls' - version 1.0, Aptara Inc.
% (c) 2013 AR
%
% Steps to compile: latex latex latex
%
% For tracking purposes => this is v1.0 - Apr. 2013

\documentclass[oneside]{ar-1col-S2O}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{lipsum}  


% Metadata Information
\jname{Annu. Rev. Biomed. Data Sci.}
\jvol{06}
\jyear{2022}
\doi{10.1146/((please add article doi))}


% Document starts
\begin{document}

% Page header
\markboth{Author}{Short Title}

% Title
\title{Title}


%Authors, affiliations address.
\author{Firstname Lastname $^{1}$
\affil{$^1$ University 1}}



% To change
% SB in abstract
% equity companies


%Abstract
\begin{abstract}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
\end{abstract}

%Keywords, etc.
\begin{keywords}
keywords
\end{keywords}
\maketitle

%Table of Contents
%\tableofcontents

% Heading 1
\section{INTRODUCTION}

\lipsum[2-24]

\end{document}
```

Here is the changed part of the class file:

```
\newdimen\typeheight\typeheight47pc%
\newdimen\typewidth\typewidth38pc%
\newlength\extramargin
\setlength\extramargin{7.5pc}
\setlength\textheight{55pc}%
\setlength\textwidth{35.5pc}%
\setlength\marginparsep {10\p@}
\setlength\marginparpush{5\p@}
\setlength\marginparwidth {2.0cm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{26.5\p@}%
\setlength\evensidemargin{08.5\p@}%
% \setlength\oddsidemargin{46.5\p@}%
% \setlength\evensidemargin{28.5\p@}%
%
\setlength\topmargin{0.5\p@}%
\setlength\footnotesep{7.35\p@}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{19.5\p@ \@plus 4\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
```

All I changed is the numbers (to reduce the margins). Now only the footer (with the page numbers) on right (odd) pages needs to be adjusted as well.

Comment: Please post here a MWE for what you've done.  Don't make us go to an external link and guess what changes you've done to the margins.

Comment: I could do that, and would be happy to do that. But you don't need my custom changes, right? All that is needed is to move the footer to the right independently of my margin changes.

Comment: @Teepeemm Also, I have tried it, but I would need to paste the entire file ar-1col-S2O.cls
which is too long to be pasted.

Comment: You're right that we don't need your custom class file.  Please work through https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497.  What have you tried to do to move the footer?

Comment: @Teepeemm  I have added an MWE. What I have tried is to change the values in the class file, but I could not find the proper parameters. Also I searched via Google and Stack Exchange for solutions, but could not find one. Thank you.

Comment: We don't need your custom class file because you should include the relevant parts in your post.  Try to remove everything that isn't related to the margins and footer.

Comment: Are you trying to achive a sort of left aligned/right aligned look?  Possibly in a fixed width box?

Comment: Teepeemm I have added the changed parts in the class file. 
@JohnKormylo yes, the footer with the page number needs to be aligned with the right edge of the main text. I reduced the margin of the main text, but the footer did not automatically adjust with it as well.

Comment: @Teepeemm is there anything else I should add? Many thanks